# switch statement not detecting some characters

Tags: c++, arguments, switch-statement

I am using a switch statement for an easy menu in C++. Everything works except for 2 cases, the letters `'U'` and `'l'`, when used during runtime act like a `cin` statement that never gets filled. Cannot enter other options and cannot stop it by entering characters, have to actually Ctrl-Z out of it. The syntax is right as far as I can tell and all other options work.

Edit: Even removing the while completely results in the same thing

```
cin >> command;

while(command!='Q')
{
  switch(command)
  {
     case 'L':
        le.left();
        break;
     case 'R':
        le.right();
        break;
     case 'I':
        cin >> str;
        le.insert(str);
        break;
     case 'D':
        le.erase();
        break;
     case 'C':
        cin >> c;
        le.change(c);
        break;
     case 'U':
        cout << "Applying uppercase";      //doesn't even print to screen
        upperList(le);
        cout << "Uppercase applied" << endl;
        break;
     case 'l':
        lowerList(le);
        break;
     case 'P':
        cout<<le;
        break;
     case 'Q':
        break;
     default:
        cout << "Invalid command.";
  }
  cin >> command;
}
```

le.insert:

```
void LineEditor::insert(const string& s)
{
for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
  L.insert(it, s.at(i));

itBegin=L.begin();  //iterator to beginning of list, used in <iterator>::distance later
}
```

upperList and its ToUpper function:

```
char ToUpper(char c)
{
c=toupper(c);
return c;
}

void upperList(LineEditor le)
{
char c;

le.setBegin();

while(!le.end())
{
  c=le.at();
  le.apply(*ToUpper, c);
  le.right();
}
}
```

and le.end()

```
bool LineEditor::end() const
{
if(it!=L.end())
  return false;
else
  return true;
}
```

Narrowed it down to LineEditor::setBegin()

```
void LineEditor::setBegin()
{
while(it!=L.begin())           //supposed to move iterator to beginning of list
  --it;
}
```

Comment: what does `le.insert` and `upperList` look like?

Comment: Why can't you just do `it = L.begin()` in `setBegin`? Why the cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
cout << "Applying uppercase";
```

is not printed because standard output is line-buffered. You need

```
cout << "Applying uppercase" << flush;
```

to flush the buffer.

Additionally, your `upperList` and `lowerList` function apparently enter an infinite cycle, which means that the iteration logic implemented inside `LineEditor` is broken somehow.

Also, it looks like you keep the string itself inside the `LineEditor` object as `L` member. At the same time you pass `LineEditor` to `upperList` and `lowerList` *by value*. That means that any changes done inside `upperList` and `lowerList` will not have any effect on the `le` from the calling code, since `upperList` and `lowerList` will work on an independent copy of `LineEditor`.

Comment: His `le.right()` function pushes the iterator forward.  For some reason he is keeping an iterator internally (he had a related question earlier and that was noted).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by internally? Is it a big issue? Like using a member function instead of accessing the iterator directly via 'le.it'?

Comment: @Zac Howland: It is strange, but it should not normally cause an infinite cycle by itself. And it looks like the code is cycling indefinitely.

Comment: AH! I looked at it a few times even thinking I was missing &...Added that, and bam good to go. Thank you!